# Why isn't Android working with Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova

I installed the latest Android Studio (3.0.1 for Mac).

I installed the latest JDK (jdk-10).

I installed the latest Node (9.8.0).

I installed the latest Cordova (8.0.0).

When I try "cordova run android", I get this:

```
(node:1972) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater
    at /Users/richardeng/PharoJSmobile/platforms/android/cordova/lib/check_reqs.js:370:19
    at _fulfilled (/Users/richardeng/PharoJSmobile/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/richardeng/PharoJSmobile/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:883:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/richardeng/PharoJSmobile/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)
    at /Users/richardeng/PharoJSmobile/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:624:44
    at runSingle (/Users/richardeng/PharoJSmobile/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/Users/richardeng/PharoJSmobile/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:112:11)
(node:1972) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1972) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

BTW, "cordova run ios" runs perfectly. Why?

Comment: There is a issue with java 1.8+ on wards i  also faced the same issue when i installed the java 1.9 i got the same error then i downgraded from 1.9 to 1.8 it started working .

Comment: It's hard to downgrade. My Mac is already upgraded to Java 1.9 and it won't let me replace it with an older version.

Comment: Okay, I managed to remove the old Java and reinstall Java 8 from scratch, but I still get pretty much the same error message, except it also complains about missing gradle.

Comment: Have u removed the old java 1.9 path from system variables? if not remove the old one and set the java 1.8 . In the Advanced system settings-->environment variables--> user variables-->C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161 and after that in system variables --> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin set like this

Comment: I'm on the Mac, not Windows. And when I execute 'cordova run android', it automatically sets the necessary environment variables: ANDROID_HOME=/Users/richardeng/android-sdk-macosx
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home
studio